# Is it possible to have an interface that has either one property or another?

Tags: typescript

I want an interface like this:

```
interface EitherOr {
  first: string;
  second: number;
}
```

But to ensure that it only has either `first` or `second`. Is this possible?

Comment: Use a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types): `type EitherOr = { first: string } | { second: number }`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) as it is already suggested in the comment. This means that the type is always one of the two types.

```
interface First {
   first: string;
}

interface Second {
   second: number;
}

type EitherOr = First | Second;
```